# SQLite or Content Providers?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

It is an application that will have a local database SQLite.
The local DB has to be updated when the data in the remote database changes.
In this case it would be convenient to use content providers?

Comment: IMHO, no. Nothing about content providers is convenient. Use a content provider if you need to expose data to other apps or core OS processes.

Comment: If you would have Simply google `ContentProvider` you would already know the answer. Read [Decide if you need a content provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html).

Answer (score 0):

Content providers are the part of getting data from native applications not from the user installed apps.
For this concept you have to use concept of background service which will detect changes and update them in db.